# Android Couldn't update app from playstore

Tags: android, google-play, updates

I have faced issue like when i want to update app from playstore it couldn't be updated. I clicked update and accept button, it shows me again update button? What is the issue on me PlayMarket or Google Services? Please help in order to fix this issue? But it works other device the problem is just related to my device?

Comment: have you used same package name as previous

Comment: yes, as i said above it works except on my device.

Comment: do you have the release version on your device or a debug version? With which key is the app on your device signed?

Comment: Please give a meaningful advices, I`m not a junior developer

Comment: That`s all yet, I think whatever options is enabled/disabled in Settings in order to work properly.

Comment: Any ideas to slove this issue?

Comment: Other applications can be updated except our app.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204057&thanks=204057&ts=1458114679#makechanges